# Javascript method to be able see if a value changes without re rendering the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, functional-programming

I am trying to be able to read a value that is boolean to see if a user did a specific action or not and I am using the ReactJS functional component style. I am trying to read the **runValue** in my code to see if the **run()** method changed the value and I want to be able to read this value without recalling the function.

I want to be able to put in my **useEffect** method this line of code;

```
Run.RunFunction().run((index) => {
  if (index) {
   \\\ do stuff here if index is true
  } else {
   ///if index is false
  } 
}
```

my code

```
 const Run = {
     RunFunction: () => {
        let runValue = false;
        return {
            run() {
                runValue = true
            },
            listener: function(val) {},
            checkStatus: function(listen) {
                this.listener = listen
            }
        }
     }, 
 }


    Run.RunFunction().checkStatus((index) => {
        if (index) {
            console.log('running')
        } else {
            console.log('not running')
        }
    });
```

I am having trouble having this code to work and I want to be able to see the value of the **runValue** initially and if it changes.

Thank you

Comment: I think in order to answer this we will need a simplified version of your whole component. Right now I'm not clear on what authValue vs runValue vs index are and how they are supposed to interact with each other. However, I think what you need is the ability to persist scope between re-renders, and subscribe to changes to it. Maybe take a look at the useState hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html for storing runValue

Comment: @ChrisBelyeu I made a mistype it is not authValue it is run value and this is not really a component in react this is basically a backend function that is to be read in the client side